# How to process this query without a CTE or sub-query

Tags: mysql

a beginner in SQL here. I just downloaded MySQL and was working with the default sakila database.

**Tables that I want to work with :**

1)*Actors-* Schema = (actor_id, first_name, last_name, last_update)

2)*Film_actor-* Schema = (actor_id, film_id, last_update)

[Desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7Ro3.png)

I want a list of actors and the number of films they have done per year, I was able to write the query but I had to use temp tables or subqueries.
Is there any other way to write this query, a way which is more efficient.

**Here is the code that I wrote**

```
With TEMP AS(
SELECT 
    concat(T1.first_name, " ",T1.last_name) as actor, 
    (T2.film_id) as fid, 
    extract(year FROM T1.last_update) as Year
FROM 
    sakila.actor as T1
left JOIN 
    sakila.film_actor as T2 ON T1.actor_id = T2.actor_id) 
    
Select 
    actor as Actor_name, count(fid) as Number_of_films, year 
FROM 
    TEMP
Group BY actor, year
ORDER BY actor asc ;
```

p.s. I don't know the norms of this website (new user), so sorry if I have written or framed the question badly.

Comment: Actually you didn't use a temp table, you just wrote a subquery and put it in the syntax of a Common Table Expression (CTE, or also sometimes called a `With` clause). That being said, it could be rewritten to be less verbose, although it may not change the execution time. This might be a good question for codereview.stackexchange.com if you don't find traction here.

Comment: the `Year` you use is the last_update of the actor table. I think it would be better to use the `release_year` field from the `film` table.  Because with your solution the year changes when the actor changes..

Comment: see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&sample=sakila&fiddle=9f32feefca125a118737929fb3a9da17)

Comment: Thank you for the help!, I tried to use group by without a subquery once but mySQL just did not let me use it.  I see the mistake now. I used 'count(film_id)' and not 'count(*)' Can you tell me why the former is wrong.

Comment: Also thank you for point out the difference between CTE and Temp Table. I see that Temp tables have completely different uses and syntax. @JNevill

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    concat(T1.first_name, " ",T1.last_name) as Actor_name, 
    count(T2.film_id) as  Number_of_films, --assumes actor will not be listed twice for same film; otherwise we need to do a count(distinct t2.film_id)
    extract(year FROM T1.last_update) as Year
 as Year
FROM sakila.actor as T1
LEFT JOIN sakila.film_actor as T2 
  ON T1.actor_id = T2.actor_id
GROUP BY concat(T1.first_name, " ",T1.last_name), extract(year FROM T1.last_update)
ORDER BY Actor_name asc, Year ;
```

GROUP BY doens't know about aliases as it executes before the select statement: as such we can't just use the alias from the select; we have to put the full formula.  This was the tricky part about combining the two queries.

**However as far as being more efficient:**

- I'd say what you have is just as good, maybe just a smidge slower because of the CTE; but not much.
- One could use "Generated Columns" so the load of data for Actor_Name and "Year" are generated as the data is updated/changed.  This would negate the need for the functions within the SQL cleaning up the SQL a bit.  if mySQL supports persistence in these columns (I'm not sure if it does) it would push the processing time of these generated columns to the insert/update instead of the select; saving some time.

NOTES:

- oracle would call these function based index
- SQL Server calls them persistant computed columns
- mySQL calls it generated columns virtual or stored...  if you're looking for performance gain on a select at a cost of storge and computing time on insert/update then use stored.  [Index doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html)

[Doc Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for the answer. I don't know what generated columns are, but I will look into them. Also, I did not know that Group By does not know aliases. Thank you for pointing it out, fundamentals like this will help me in my SQL journey.

Comment: Take a look at sql order of operations. It helps explain why.